# Wrong output measuring time with MacOS, C, VirtualBox and time.h

Tags: c, time, virtualbox, macos-sierra, time.h

I'm making a performance experiment with VirtualBox, but something very strange is happening with time when I try to measure it with **clock()**. Somehow the output through this method is smaller then the output result from **time()** (And apparently the right one).  The following results are obtained without any VM running.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
int main()
{   
    clock_t start, end;
    double cpu_time_used;
    long int i = 0;
    time_t start_t = time(NULL);
    printf("%d\n", start_t);
    start = clock();
    while (i<1000000000){
        if(i%100==0)
            printf("%d\n", i);
        i++;
    }
    end = clock();
    printf("Time spent: %g seconds (time)\n", (double)(time(NULL)-start_t));
    cpu_time_used = ((double) (end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("Time spent: %g seconds (clock)\n", cpu_time_used);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Time spent: 41 seconds (time)
Time spent: 26.9069 seconds (clock)
```

System:

```
Macbook Pro 13 mid-2012
OS: MacOS Sierra (10.12.4)
Processor: 2,5GHz Intel Core i5 (4 cores)
Memory: 4GB (1600MHz DDR3) 
HD: SSD 240GB
```

Does anyone have any clue why this is happening?

Comment: `time` measures the wall-clock, `clock` measures the elapsed CPU-time for the process (on Unix and similar systems). Those two are not the same.

Comment: Because of multitasking and other OS stuff, your program took 41 seconds to run but only had access to the cpu for 26.9 seconds,

Comment: Thank you @JohnnyMopp it seems plausible. But what other way would I have to measure the execution time in miliseconds?

Comment: On OSX, your options for high-precision wall-clock time are [`gettimeofday`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/gettimeofday.2.html) and [`mach_absolute_time`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1398/_index.html).  [`clock_gettime`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime) is not available, unfortunately (this is the preferred function on most other Unixes).